# Learn how to arrange elements correctly using CSS

Tags: css, css-float, position

I'm trying to be a back-end web developer. But learning a little of CSS just to put it in my toolbox if i needed it someday.

I know about CSS properties and stuff. All what i really "suck" in is arranging elements in CSS. I really waste so much time trying to figure out why does this element behaves in weird manner like this, or how to get that element to the left, or how to align elements the way i have in my mind.

I don't want to take much time learning it as i'm moving forward for what i'm going to be specialized in. So if there're videos or a crash courses on arranging elements using `floats` or `position` property or any other good technique to achieve that i would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started experimenting with **CSS** by downloading some free templates available. Just try searching in Google. There are plenty of.

**[Creating a CSS layout from scratch](http://www.subcide.com/articles/creating-a-css-layout-from-scratch/)** is a nice place to start your journey. You may understand CSS by going through SIMPLE, beginner level tutotal from **[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)**.

You may have a look at **[CSS Layouts: 40+ Tutorials, Tips, Demos and Best Practices](http://www.noupe.com/css/css-layouts-40-tutorials-tips-demos-and-best-practices.html)** to get some inspiration and to develop some ideas by your own.

You may also try a couple of CSS softwares like **[Westciv Style Master](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/)** and **[Top Style](http://www.topstyle4.com/)** (but they dont come free). The **[Resource](http://westciv.com/style_master/house/index.html)** section in westciv site is really helpful for beginners. It has got Guide, Tools, Tutorials etc. Also you may have a look at **[complete css guide](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/css_tutorial/)** in their site.

Finally, you  may experiment CSS with the help of **[11 Useful Online Tools for Better CSS Development](http://webdesignledger.com/tools/11-useful-online-tools-for-better-css-development)**

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 3):

No videos, but two other suggestions:

1) You should take a little time (a few hours maybe) and get used to the [CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). It is worth getting a *precise* idea of how CSS works. fa(You know, a few hours of trying out can save you a few minutes of reading what's going on ;-))

2) Get yourself a suitable tool (I recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox) and play around a little with the CSS properties of your favorite page "in real time". Very convenient and efficient to get used to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I got to learn css pretty fast by study other people CSS and tinkling with it using firebug trying all sort... the more advance the CSS the more you learn, i think you should pretty try the same thing too

Answer (score 1):

I learned most of my CSS knowledge between [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp), questions on this site, and Google searches.

Honestly, the only way to absorb any real knowledge is to actually USE what you're learning. Just as you probably couldn't walk if you only ever heard what walking was like, you probably won't develop the skills to be a good CSS coder(or any type of coder for that matter) if you don't practice what you're learning.

That's why I like W3Schools, since they put examples into their tutorials to let you practice what they are trying to show you.

Good positioning reference:
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Good Float reference:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/